# SoundManager, Scrub bar, does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

First of all I am using SoundManager on my website,

But I have a problem in adding it to my website, so to understand the problem better, please check the website first: http://tinyurl.com/8bugpc7

I am trying to impediment to sound manager on by website. The website is kinda vertical slider. So there is a menu but all items are linked to a specific class of the page. Music link is the third option (Page 3). But when I added the 360 music player the scrub bar did not work correctly, that means wherever I click on the bar, it only goes to a specific place. Actually it does not play where I click on.

BUT when I moved the player to the first class (first page) the scrub bar works correctly. So I guess there is a problem with those previous classes (pages).

I spend hours but really cant understand the problem, can anyone check it for me and tell me what is wrong?

if you need to download the files, here is the link: 
http://tinyurl.com/8q83gzu

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called in 360player.js: line 701 for me. Look for:

```
this.mmh = function(e) {
```

Here the deltaX variable is being calculated incorrectly, most likely due to the offset created by your carousel. I solved the problem on my page by subtracting this same offset from the deltaX variable.
Here is the new function with pseudocode to modify it:

```
this.mmh = function(e) {
  /**
   * Here you need to find the offset from the left of the page
   * and assign it to a variable. In your case, it is simply the window's
   * width multiplied by 2.
  */
  offSet = 2 * $(window).width();
  if (typeof e === 'undefined') {
    e = window.event;
  }
  var oSound = self.lastTouchedSound,
      coords = self.getMouseXY(e),
      x = coords[0],
      y = coords[1],
      /* here you subtract your offset and scrubbing should work again */
      deltaX = x-(oSound._360data.canvasMidXY[0]-offSet),
      deltaY = y-oSound._360data.canvasMidXY[1],
      angle = Math.floor(fullCircle-(self.rad2deg(Math.atan2(deltaX,deltaY))+180));
  oSound.setPosition(oSound.durationEstimate*(angle/fullCircle));
  self.stopEvent(e);
  return false;
};
```